# Having trouble with SQL 'in'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I want to search for all records in `product_description` who match a certain brand, and also whose status in another table `product` is '1'. This is how far I've got, but I'm tripping up somewhere:

```
SELECT brand,
       name,
       product_id
FROM   product_description
WHERE  brand = $brandname
       AND product_id IN (SELECT product_id,
                                 status
                          FROM   product
                          WHERE  status = '1');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove status from the sub-select

Comment: Remove status in subquery because product id should compare only with product id not with status.

Comment: You should have used Google at first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason:**

Inner query should return only 1 column if you want to use it with `IN`.

**Solution:**

Remove `status` from the inner query. Also use single quotes `'` around the variable `$brandname`:

```
$sql = "SELECT brand,name,product_id 
        FROM product_description 
        where brand = '$brandname'
              and product_id in 
                    (SELECT product_id FROM product where status='1')";
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I also use this with 'like'?  `where brand like = '%$searchtext%' and product_id in`

Comment: @themartin: You can use like as : `product_id like '13%'`. But not with `IN`.

Comment: Ah crap. I'm using this code to search the database as people type, so when people are typing "Adi" I want it to be pulling in Adidas. Can you see any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

No need to fetch `status` in the sub query. Try with this -

```
$sql = "SELECT 
           brand,name,product_id 
        FROM product_description 
        WHERE brand ='$brandname' 
        AND product_id in (SELECT product_id FROM product where status='1')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to update your query as

```
"SELECT brand,name,product_id FROM product_description where brand 
= '$brandname' and product_id in (SELECT product_id FROM product where 
status='1')";
```

1. You need to enclose your variable `$brandname` within single quotes if its not an integer
2. Your sub-query is returning multiple values so you need to select only `product_id`

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for definite without an error or an output of the query, but I think you should not be selecting "status" in the subquery, as you are checking if a specific product_id is within a result set of both a product_id and a status. Try rewriting the subquery so that only product_id is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Join your tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT d.brand, d.name, d.product_id
FROM   product_description AS d
JOIN   product AS p ON d.product_id = p.product_id AND p.status = '1'
WHERE  d.brand = '$brandname'";
```

Best practise is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)